# Getting Epoch Time at Compile Time

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, epoch

Context: I'm writing a sort of non-trivial client-server UDP multicast program that I'm deploying on some wireless nodes.  The means of deployment is a script I wrote that broadcast pings the network that these nodes sit on, gets a list of the nodes (based on IP addresses), deploys my package, and installs it.  It has come to my attention that sometimes not all the nodes are detected at the time of deployment, and the most current package I'm developing is not installed.  Ultimately, it can be the case in which the server running on one node is older than a client who wishes to communicate with the server.  Because the server gets packets, and allocates memory depending on entries in this packet, if the structure changes, the server usually crashes in a segfault.  As a solution, I'm thinking about implementing version numbers in the packets that get sent between client and server such that if the server/client reads a packet in which the version number isn't the same (or is garbage because of restructuring of packets), this packet gets ignored, and a log is updated, or an emergency packet is sent to the original sender.

So, I'm trying to come up with the best way of getting this "version number" at compile time that can sit in a header as a `#define`.  I've looked up the `__time__` preprocessor macro, but this is in the form of a string.  Is there a way to get the epoch time during compile time so that I can bitmask it into an unsigned int (which should only roll over after 136 years, if I'm thinking about this correctly)?

Sorry if I'm being unclear.

Comment: Write a 5-line C program that does `cout "const long x = " << time() << ";" << endl;`, then redirect to a file?

Comment: Of course, a better solution would simply be to send, as part of the packet, the size the packet needs to be at the other end.

Comment: Are you sure you want the version to change every time you compile?  It seems unlikely (to me as an uninformed observer) that the packet structure would not change with every single compilation. It would seem that the version change would be more of a conscious effort where you "manually" change it occasionally.  I'm just curious.

Comment: @MarkWilkins: Yes, I was thinking that too. Especially during development, it will be really annoying to have to distribute out new executabled every time the code is recompiled simply because a small change to some debug logging, or some such.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, I understand what you're saying, but I do have to distribute the executable to at least ONE of the nodes, given I make a trivial change like debug logging.  The difference between that and even 10 nodes is next to nothing.  Why NOT distribute the fix, no matter how small to ALL nodes I'm testing?  Doing this version number thing is just more 'automatic', I suppose.  I /could/ manually change the number only when I change packet structure, but what if I forget?

Comment: What I used in such cases is, using the version number from CVS. Maybe your versioning system has something similar like that?

Comment: Here is an [example which seems appropriate](http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17269831) (it is copyrighted, licensed w/LGPL so not included as an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your build system, but if you're using gmake, you
can do something like:

```
CXX_TIME = -DBUILDTIME=$(shell python -c "import time; print( int( time.time() ) )" )
```

Add this into your other compiler options, and then use the
macro `BUILDTIME` in your code.

(This supposes that you've got Python installed in your path.
If not, you can either install it, or do something similar with
a tool you have installed.)

Comment: You could also write a shell script with `sed` and `date` if you don't want to use python.

Comment: Could just use `$(shell date "+%s")`

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for... I just didn't know you could do this in a Makefile (they're not really my thing).  Although I prefer @jxh's method of avoiding Python.  Thank you :)

Comment: @jxh Except that `date` doesn't have a `"%s"` format specifier, at least according to Posix.  Some particular platform might support it; CygWin does, for example, so if portability to different platforms isn't an issue, this might be the preferred solution.  (The "best" solution here depends on context: it might be the non-portable use of `date`, Python, Ruby or whatever other tool you habitually use for scripting.  I probably would have mentioned the `date` solution myself, had I been aware of it, but I learned Unix on Sun machines, and use the Posix docs as my reference.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: It seems to be a GNU extension, which could explain why it applies to CygWin.

Comment: @jxh CygWin uses the same code base as GNU.  At my present location, I only have access to Windows, and CygWin.  When I saw it in CygWin, I suspected that it was GNU, but since I couldn't be sure, I thought I'd limit my statement to what I could actually verify.  (One way to ensure portability would be to install the GNU tool chain everywhere.  Which you have to do partially anyway, since `$(shell...)` is GNU make, and not standard Posix make.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the epoch from the `__DATE__` preprocessor macro.

Below the `getCompileTimeEpoch()` function, which in turn depends on two other simple auxiliary functions that return the month number and another one to switch the month acronym to lower case.

It puzzles me how **GCC** developers have introduced a macro with a human readable date and not with an epoch, from which anything else about a date can be derived with maximum reliability.

You may very easily add the time from the `__TIME__` macro, should you need it added to the epoch.

I opted for this solution, as it keeps everything inside the code and does not depend on compiler options.

```
char *tolowercase(char *letstr){
    int l;
    for(l=0;l<=strlen(letstr);l++){
        if(letstr[l]>=65 && letstr[l]<=92){
            letstr[l]=letstr[l]+32;
        }
    }
    return letstr;
}

int getMonFromAbbr(char *abbr){
    if (strlen(abbr) > 0)
        tolowercase(abbr);
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "jan") == 0 )
        return 0;
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "feb") == 0 )
        return 1;
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "mar") == 0 )
        return 2;
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "apr") == 0 )
        return 3;
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "may") == 0 )
        return 4;
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "jun") == 0 )
        return 5;
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "jul") == 0 )
        return 6;
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "aug") == 0 )
        return 7;
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "sep") == 0 )
        return 8;
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "oct") == 0 )
        return 9;
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "nov") == 0 )
        return 10;
    if ( strcmp(abbr, "dec") == 0 )
        return 11;
    return(-1);
}

// Convert from __DATE__ macro
uint64_t getCompileTimeEpoch(){
    char date_macro[20]="";
    strcpy(date_macro, __DATE__);
    char *token;
    int yea=0;
    int mon=0;
    int day=0;
    token=strtok(date_macro, " ");
    if (token != NULL){
        mon=getMonFromAbbr(token);
        token=strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (token != NULL){
            day=atoi(token);
            token=strtok(NULL, " ");
            if (token != NULL){
                yea=atoi(token);
                struct tm t;
                time_t epoch_t;
                t.tm_year = yea-1900;    // Year - 1900
                t.tm_mon = mon;          // Month, where 0 = jan
                t.tm_mday = day;         // Day of the month
                t.tm_hour = 0;
                t.tm_min = 0;
                t.tm_sec = 0;
                t.tm_isdst = 0;         // Is DST on? 1 = yes, 0 = no, -1 = unknown
                epoch_t = mktime(&t);               
                return epoch_t;
            }           
        }
    }
    return(-1);
}
```

Comment: epoch time doesn't account for leap seconds, so to say *"anything else about a date can be derived with maximum precission and reliability."*  is misleading where precision is required. Nice work though, so thanks!

Comment: Well, my comment is, of course relative to the ongoing matter, which is to obtain a reliable date. You can reliably get a date from an epoch, no mater if the epoch is not precise enough. Thus, what I meant (probably it was my fault) is that you can reliably get a date out of an epoch, not that the epoch itself would be reliable, that's a different tale.